# python: how to use if while returning object

Tags: python-2.7

How can I use if statement while returning an object?

Code:

```
def to_json(self):
    return {
        'some_key': some_data,
        'some_details': [
            if self.__some_details: # if it is not None
                detail.to_json() for detail in self.__details
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to have happen if `self.__some_details` *is* `None`? Should the `some_details` key in the dictionary refer to an empty list, or should that key be omitted completely?

Answer (score 1):

Python has a version of `if`/`else` that can be used in an expression, rather than as a statement. It's a little odd, since the syntax is `value1 if condition else value2`. In your dictionary, that would be something like:

```
def to_json(self):
    return {
        'some_key': some_data,
        'some_details': [detail.to_json() for detail in self.__details]
                        if self.__some_details
                        else [] # or else None?
    }
```

Note that the condition is outside the brackets that form the list comprehension. There's no way to make an entire list comprehension conditional the way you had it. You can put a condition on each value (e.g. `[x for x in xs if some_condition(x)]`) but that syntax requires `xs` to exist and be iterable even if the condition is false, and it could be wasteful if the condition doesn't depend on the `x` values. The `if`/`else` syntax used above short circuits, so the list comprehension won't be evaluated if the condition is falsey.

It's not entirely clear what you want your code to do if the condition isn't met, so I've guessed at the empty list as the alternative to the list comprehension. You could also use `None` or whatever other value you want. If however, you don't want the `'some_details'` key to be added to the dictionary at all when the condition isn't met, this approach won't work. You'll need to use multiple statements to build the dictionary in that situation:

```
result = {'some_key': somedata}
if self.__some_details:
    result['some_details'] = [detail.to_json() for detail in self.__details]
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following suitable?

```
def to_json(self):
    if self.__some_details:
        some_details = [ detail.to_json() for detail in self.__details ]
    else:
        some_details = []
    return {
        'some_key': some_data,
        'some_details': some_details
    }
```

Comment: `some_details = detail.to_json() for detail in self.__details` isn't valid syntax. You probably want square brackets around the expression on the right side of the `=`, making it a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed now.  I'd copied it from his original code but neglected to copy the brackets (which were on separate lines).